# Mongoose Populate method return object in object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose populate -

```
let allLeaders = await DAOManager.populate(
        models.Users,
        { firstName: "Mayank" },
        {firstName: 1, lastName: 1, district: 1},
        { lean : true},
        { path: "userId", select: "county designation gender" }
    );
```

In user model -

```
let Users = new schema({
userId: { type: schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'hubiloUsers' }})
```

Output :

```
 {
    "_id": "5a05799b936a8c707f0e022f",
    "userId": {
        "_id": "5a057915c31eb5601da9b75f",
        "designation": "CTO ",
        "gender": "male",
        "county": "India"
    },
    "firstName": "Mayank", 
    "lastName": "Sharma", 
    "district": "ABC"
    }
```

Problem --- In output I got userid object. Is there anyway I can get the userId output data outside.  so I can sent the data to the views or frontend. Thank you very much in advance

Comment: `find` and `populate` query are not worthy to perform such operations. You have to use aggregation function to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can user $project in aggregation for the same.

Answer (score 0):

I've asked the developer of Mongoose about this before, and he says it's by design. I do agree with you that it sometimes makes more sense as a flat structure but what can you do!

You can read the issue here: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/7281

You will have to change it to a flat structure yourself after the operation.